# How to inspect element if right click doesn't open the browser menu?

Tags: firefox

I try to inspect element with right click on a specific element, but instead the browser menu, a website menu is opened.

How can I open the browser menu, and then choose the inspect element option?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+U, or use the F12 Developer Tools.